# Why firefox is default browser in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, xdg, default-browser

I have a lot of apps which ignore xfce browser settings: for example banshee. It still opens links in firefox, but I set google-chrome as default. It is default in xfce-preferred-apps, it is default in

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser:

* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       автоматический режим
  1            /usr/bin/chromium-browser       40        ручной режим
  2            /usr/bin/epiphany-browser       85        ручной режим
  3            /usr/bin/firefox                40        ручной режим
  4            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       ручной режим
  5            /usr/bin/netsurf                100       ручной режим
  6            /usr/bin/opera                  120       ручной режим
```

I have even tried

```
export XDG_BROWSER=/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

When I removed firefox - link was opened in chrome, but after installing - again firefox

How to unset firefox fully?

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37043/70524

Answer (score 4):

```
$ xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
```

Helped

Comment: For me, this also wass needed to support https links: $ xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/https